# Define and sort array of array content in TypeScript and Node.js

Tags: node.js, arrays, typescript, sorting

Just took up TypeScript a couple of weeks ago without much knowledge in JavaScript.

I am trying to go through all the files in the specified directory and put each file name (`string`) and change time (`number`) into an array of array and sort by change time.

It looks like this: `[['natalie.jpg', 143], ['mike.jpg', 20], ['john.jpg', 176], ['Jackie.jpg', 6]]`

Problem 1: I do not know how to specify the inner array content, string and number. Type? Interface? Class? Tuple?

Problem 2: I do not know how to sort by change time in ascending order, so that the array changes to: `[['Jackie.jpg', 6], ['mike.jpg', 20], ['natalie.jpg', 143], ['john.jpg', 176]]`

```
import fs from 'fs'

const dirPath = '/home/me/Desktop/'

type imageFileDesc = [string, number] // tuple

const imageFileArray = [imageFileDesc] // ERROR HERE!

function readImageFiles (dirPath: string) {
  try {
    const dirObjectNames = fs.readdirSync(dirPath)

    for (const dirObjectName of dirObjectNames) {
      const dirObject = fs.lstatSync(dirPath + '/' + dirObjectName)
      if (dirObject.isFile()) {
        imageFileArray.push([dirObjectName, dirObject.ctimeMs]) // ERROR HERE!
      }
    }

    imageFileArray.sort(function (a: number, b: number) {
      return b[1] - a[1] // ERROR HERE! Can we do something like b.ctime - a.ctime?
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in reading ' + dirPath)
  }
}

readImageFiles(dirPath)
console.log(imageFileArray)
```

Comment: Is the type you're looking for `[ string, number ][]`?

Comment: @bitomic: When I change to const imageFileArray = [ string, number ][], it says, " 'string/number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Comment: You are incorrectly using types, I suggest you to check the Typescript Documentation at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/. They explain it way better than I could in a comment. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import * as fs from 'fs'

// Read files in folder
const files = fs.readdirSync( './files' )
// This will store the file name and their modification time
const imageFileArray: [ string, Date ][] = []

for ( const file of files ) {
    // You can get a file's last modified time through fs.stat
    const stats = fs.statSync( `./files/${file}` )
    const modifiedTime = stats.mtime
    // Push a tuple containing the filename and the last modified time
    imageFileArray.push( [ file, modifiedTime ] )
}

// Sort from older to newer
const sorted = imageFileArray.sort( (a, b) => a[1].getTime() - b[1].getTime() )

console.log( sorted )
```

The modified time returns a `Date` object. If you want to sort from newer to older, just invert the operation in the `sort` function.